# License error when connecting Kibana to Keycloak

Tags: elasticsearch, oauth, kibana, openid-connect

We are configuring single sign-on using an OpenID Connect provider (Keycloak) in our ELK deployment and are seeing the following error in the browser when accessing the Kibana dashboard:

```
{
"statusCode": 403,
"error": "Forbidden",
"message": "[security_exception] current license is non-compliant for [oidc], with { license.expired.feature=\"oidc\" }"
}
```

I have a platinum license with Elastic, and it doesn't expire until October.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use advanced security features in ECK such a OIDC and SAML integration, an Enterprise level subscription is required per Elastic's website:

https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions/enterprise